# bitrock installer - can it overwrite based on bin diff?

Tags: bitrock

I read the bitrock documentation where is mentions that overwrite only if newer is allowed based on timestamps. By any chance we can make bitrock allow overwrite only if newer based on bindiff and not based on timestamps?

Thanks!